# Loop through hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some functionality where I client can create custom fields, what I'm trying to do now is to loop through that data but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here are the params when we create or update a record, I've removed some as I'm only trying to loop through `custom_fields_attr`

```
Parameters: {... "custom_fields_attr"=>{"1"=>"testing12", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}}, ...}
```

I have the following code:

```
<!-- start of custom fields -->
<% if Contact.has_custom_fields %>
  <div class="form-block">
    <h2 class="txt-title-alt">Custom Fields</h2>

    <% Contact.custom_fields.in_groups_of(2).each do |field| %>
      <div class="l-row-block clearfix">
        <% field.each do |item| %>
          <div class="l-06col l-ml-12col l-md-12col">
            <div class="field field_display l-row-block clearfix">
              <p class="like_p clearfix">
                <strong class="l-06col">
                  <%= item.label %>:
                </strong>
                
                <span class="value l-06col">
                  <%= item.value %>
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<!-- end of custom fields -->
```

I have a custom fields table which is where we get the label from but I need to get the value from the `custom_fields_attr` hash

**Edit**
The output of `@contact.custom_fields_attr` is

```
>> @contact.custom_fields_attr
=> {"1"=>"test field123"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `field.each do |item|` try `field.each do |key, value|`. This lets you access the `key` and `value` of each hash pair in your block.

Comment: I can't seem to get the value from the `custom_fields_value` table, the label comes from the `custom_fields` table

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me what is the output of `Contact.custom_fields`?

Can you tell, how the client is creating the custom fields, because if they are params send to the controller, you can access the params in the controller, in this case you want "custom_fields_attr", you can call it by params["custom_fields_attr"] and then to loop through it `params["custom_fields_attr"].each do |key, value|` calling in each time key = "1" and value = "testing12" then key = "2" and value = "" and etc.

Comment: the error is because `params["custom_fields_attr"]` is nil, so you have to ask first if it exists with  `if params["custom_fields_attr"] ` to look first if a params with that key is being send.